# Why is the fullstop not recognised?

Tags: antlr4

This grammar:

```
grammar TextBlock;
textBlock: sentence+ EOF;
entence: word+ FullStop;
word: LETTER+;
LETTER: [a-zA-Z];
FullStop: '.';
```

Results in:

```
1:14 token recognition error at: '.'
2:28 token recognition error at: '.'
3:73 token recognition error at: '.'
1:0 mismatched input 'This' expecting 'and'
3:29 extraneous input 'more' expecting {, 'and'}
3:44 extraneous input 'is' expecting {'and', '.'}
```

The input is:

```
This is a text.
It consists of several lines.
Each line consists of one or more Words and is terminated with a fullstop.
```

I am new to ANTLR and tested the grammar in ANTLR Lab.
Why is the '.' not recognised?
How can the strange output (line 0,29,44) be explained?
Thanks for your help

The following modification did not help:

```
sentence: word+ FullStop {getText().length() > 1};
```

The following slightly improved the output:

```
WS: ('\t' | '\n' | '\r' )+ -> skip ;
```

But still the error is:

```
1:14 token recognition error at: '.'
2:28 token recognition error at: '.'
3:73 token recognition error at: '.'
1:0 mismatched input 'This' expecting 'or'
3:29 extraneous input 'more' expecting {'or', '.'}
```

Comment: Token recognition error is output from the lexer. Your lexer rules don't recognize a space `' '`. But some of the errors don't look they're from this grammar, such as 'and' and 'or' tokens. That indicates your build environment is not working. Remove all generated files .tokens .java .interp, regenerate, recompile from scratch assuming your target is Java.

Comment: If you include the space char in your `WS` rule, `WS: ('\t' | '\n' | '\r' | ' ')+ -> skip ;`, the parser will parse the input correctly: https://pasteboard.co/ku7M1AHQZxCb.png

Comment: I removed the space from WS and put it into LETTER: [a-zA-Z ]; this works. In addition it did an my error in ANTLR Lab by choosing a wrong tab. Things are better now. Thanks